# Testrpc some times not returning event after transaction execution

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testrpc, events

I am using testrpc to test my contract
While executing some functions in my contract I have observed some inconstancy in responses from testrpc, Same function call give me 3 different results at different times.

> 1.Function executed properly and returned tx.Hash and received event callback successfully.
>   2.Function executed properly and returned tx.Hash But dont received event callback.
>   3.Transaction failed to execute with error showing invalid JSON rpc.
>   NOTE:- I haven't restarted or stopped testrpc during these three calls and it was happening pretty often.

Here is the contract code

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4.8;

contract AssetManagement {
    struct Asset {
    uint assetId;
    string assetCode;
    string assetName;
    string serviceTag;
}

    mapping (uint=>Asset) assetList;
    event onAddNewAsset(uint assetId,string assetCode,string assetName,string serviceTag);
    event onAssetAssignment(uint assetId,string assetName,uint userId,string userName);
    event onAssetReturn(uint assetId,string assetName,uint userId);
    event onGetAssignemnt(uint[] assetIds);

    // User User Id to array of Asset Id
    mapping(uint => uint[]) userAssets;
    //array of uint for assetIds
    uint[] assetsArray;
    //object of struct
    Asset asset;
    string assetNameToLog;


    function createNewAsset(uint assetId,string assetCode,string assetName,string serviceTag) public{
       asset.assetId=assetId;
       asset.assetCode=assetCode;
       asset.assetName=assetName;
       asset.serviceTag=serviceTag;
       assetList[assetId]=asset;
       onAddNewAsset(assetId,assetCode,assetName,serviceTag);
    }

    function assignAsset(uint userId, uint assetId, string userName)public {
        //add reference to userAssetRefeneces array
        assetsArray=userAssets[userId];//get existing array

        assetsArray.push(assetId);//push new refernce to aaray
        userAssets[userId]=assetsArray;//add new array to mapping
        assetNameToLog=assetList[assetId].assetName;
        onAssetAssignment(assetId,assetNameToLog,userId,userName);
    }

    function returnAsset(uint userId, uint assetId)public {
        //add reference to userAssetRefeneces array
        assetsArray=userAssets[userId];//get existing array

        uint index=IndexOf(assetsArray,assetId);//get index of assetId to be removed 
        if(index>0){
        delete assetsArray[index-1];//remove the asset Id from array
        userAssets[userId]=assetsArray;//add new array to mapping
        assetNameToLog=assetList[assetId].assetName;
        onAssetReturn(assetId,assetNameToLog,userId);
        }
    }

    function getAssetAssignment(uint userId)public returns (uint[] assetIds) {
        assetIds=userAssets[userId];
        onGetAssignemnt(assetIds);
    }

    function IndexOf(uint[] values, uint value)public returns(uint) {
        uint length=values.length;
        uint i = 0;
            while (values[i] != value) {
              i++;
              if(i==length){
                  return 0;
              }
            }
        return i+1;
    }
}
```

Well when I call the function `assignAsset()` or `returnAsset()` some times it return the event immediately but some times it refuse to return the events after a long wait also I am not getting events callback.

Here is the JavaScript code I am using to call the function and events.

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
var assetReturnEvent = contract.onAssetReturn();
var assetAssignmentEvent = contract.onAssetAssignment();

contract.assignAsset.sendTransaction(userId,assetId,userName,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:1000000},function (error, result){ 
        if(!error){
            assetAssignmentEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                  }
                  console.log("saved"+result);
                  assetAssignmentEvent.stopWatching();
                });
        } else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

contract.returnAsset.sendTransaction(userId,assetId,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:1000000},function (error, result){ 
        if(!error){
            assetReturnEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                  }
                  console.log("Removed"+result);
                  assetReturnEvent.stopWatching();
                });
        } else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Is there any thing I am doing wrong?? Or its just a testrpc issue??

Comment: It could be a timing issue? You should start watching for the event *before* you make the transaction.

Comment: @smarx I will try doing this, But I dont think that should be an issue as I am doing so many transaction is this same way and all of them are doing fine, I am facing issues with this particular function call